# Checkboxes - print checked values in checkbox from database

Tags: php, database, checkbox

In insert form I am using check boxes to insert values in database. Now, I want to get checked values in edit form so I can check new values or uncheck checked values. 
First I get values from database (I am using pdo, I will not post connection code to db- it works):

```
get oprmea from database
$sql_oprema = "SELECT Oprema FROM dbo_emarketing_stavke_oprema WHERE Partner='$id'";
  $n = $conn->query($sql_oprema);

  while ($r = $n -> fetch()) {
    $oprema_sql = $r['Oprema']; 
  }
```

I get values when I dump variables, output is not NULL. 
I am using function to store values in database. Now I want to use same function for editing if posssible.

```
function emarketing_oprema(){
    $link = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "le30mu09", "websoft");
    $link->set_charset("utf8");
    $sql=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `dbo_emarketing_oprema` order by OpremaId asc ");

    while($record = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="oprema[]" value="'.$record['OpremaId']. '">' . $record['OpremaNaziv'] . ' <br/><br/> </input>';
    }
}
```

I was wondering is it possible to use this function to get checked values checked.

Comment: 1. First you said you use PDO now `mysqli_*` ?! 2. Yes it is possible 3. What is your problem now?

Comment: "possible to use this function to get checked values checked" Just so I understand; you want it to add "checked" to the input if the value?

Comment: Added tags and removed noise

Answer (score 0):

use checked attribute

`<input type="checkbox" checked>`

or like this

`<input type="checkbox" checked="checked">`

You php will look like this:

```
 while($record = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
       data='<input type="checkbox" name="oprema[]" value="'.$record["OpremaId"];
       if(isset($record['checked'])) {//field in the database
         data+=' checked="checked';
       }
       data+='">'. $record["OpremaNaziv"].'</br>';
    }
```